# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <input> in <div>

Tags: next.js

Whenever I check for the existence of the condition isAuthorized (true or false) I get this error message on the console. Basically the error refers to server-side rendering, but I can't identify where I should fix it. When i remove isAuthorized the error disappears.

I have my context, I return isAuthorized as true or false depending on the existence of the token in the cookie.

**GlobalContext.js**

```
const Global = createContext();

export function GlobalContextProvider({ children }) {
  const { push } = useRouter();

  const userCookie = Cookies.getJSON("user");

  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(() => {
    if (userCookie) return userCookie;
    if (!userCookie) return {};
  });

  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(() => {
    return !authUser || Object.keys(authUser).length == 0 ? false : true;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthorized) {
      return push("/auth/login");
    }
  }, [isAuthorized]);

  const value = {
    isAuthorized,
    setIsAuthorized,
    authUser,
    setAuthUser,
  };

  return <Global.Provider value={value}>{children}</Global.Provider>;
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(Global);
```

**Index.jsx**

```
export default function PanelLayout({ children, title }) {
  const { push } = useRouter();
  const { isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized } = useGlobalContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const userData = Cookies.getJSON("user");

    if (!userData || !userData.access_token) {
      return push("/auth/login");
      setIsAuthorized(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isAuthorized && (
        <>
          <Head>
          // Content
          </Head>
          <input type="checkbox" id="sidebar-toggle" />
          <div className="main-content">
           // Content
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is `useGlobalContext` coming from? Could you share the code for it?

Comment: @juliomalves I edited my question with the context

Comment: The line `const userCookie = Cookies.getJSON("user");` should happen inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: It was really necessary to put it inside useEffect, thanks! -  @juliomalves

Answer (score 0):

use this code in routes file where all the routes with components are placed.
and place this useEffect there if this condition meets give the access to that routes otherwise redirect it to login.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const userData = Cookies.getJSON("user");

    if (!userData || !userData.access_token) {
      return push("/auth/login");
      setIsAuthorized(false);
    }
  }, []);
```